# Отправка личных сообщений в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android

Делаю простое приложение, мессенджер, с базой данных MySQL, чтобы сообщения приходили сразу, как только другой пользователь их отправил, как вк, телеграм и тд.

В Интернете все примеры и уроки используют FireBase, но мне хотелось бы это сделать со своей БД, чтобы была возможность отправлять сообщения на лету и желательно без спама на сервер запросов каждую секунду для проверки новых сообщений.

Кто подскажет в какую сторону копать, может, библиотеки какие-то?

Comment: Вам нужен `FirebaseCloudMessaging` - с его помощью вы со своего сервера сможете отправить на девайсы сообщения с к-л информацией, например о том, что пришло новое сообщение. При этом с базой данных это никак связано не будет. Не использовать такой механизм - не выйдет. Гугл тут монополист и сторонние решения в реальном мире использовать не выйдет.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться тогда

Answer (score 0):

Вы конечно попытайтесь сделать, получите опыт разработки, но в одного далеко не зайдете к сожалению, тут нужна команда.

Что примерно вам нужно:

1. Сервер с базой и логикой
2. FCM для пробуждения приложения
3. В приложении сокеты на сервер т.к FCM не гарантирует доставки сообщений
4. Дофига времени, но для обучения нормально или более 10М руб в год на команду